# I am doing file input/output, and I am attempting to locate a string of characters within a json file and replace them with another string

Tags: c++, io

I am currently writing a program that automates a game I play. I am doing this as a side project and I am currently stuck on a file input/output issue. All the text information stored inside the json file gets fully deleted once I finish running the program. I am trying to find certain phrase in a json file and then replace it with a different one. I made multiple functions to help assist me in doing this. I am utilizing one function to find the line specified within the file, and then another line to replace the string I located with a string I made, based on splicing using a mixture of hard-coded text and a user inputted string. I am aware that I am using cin >> rather than getline and using strings in c++ but I promise you that is not the issue at hand here. The problem is that my entire file's content is being deleted and I am not quite sure why. I will link my code below with a picture of the output and hopefully someone can help me out here because I am genuinely confused, especially since this seems like such a rudimentary task. I took out segments of the code because the entire project is pretty extensive, if there is anything missing down below or anything is unclear please let me know in the comments.

```
string FindFullLine(std::ifstream& file, unsigned int num){
    std::string s;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        std::getline(file, s);
    return s;

}
bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}
```

^^ separate functions that are being used in this small piece of code below

```
        string champo = " \"mainChamp\": ";
        string apo = "\",";
        string champ, ban, gamemode, newchamp;
        cout << "What champion would you like to pick? " << endl;
        cin >> champ;                   //getline doesnt work; cin is not causing the issue
        cout << "\nWhat champion would you like to ban? " << endl;
        cin >> ban;
        cout << "\nWhat gamemode would you like to pick? " << endl;
        cin >> gamemode;
        newchamp = "    \"mainChamp\": \"";
        newchamp += champ;
        newchamp.append(apo);
        ifstream yuumi ("C:\\forfuncoding\\bot\\Yuumi Bot Extension Fix\\bot\\config.json");        //opening file stream for input
        ofstream yuumi1 ("C:\\forfuncoding\\bot\\Yuumi Bot Extension Fix\\bot\\config.json");       //opening file stream for output
        if(!yuumi || !yuumi1){
            cout << "Error opening up files! " << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        string s = FindFullLine(yuumi, 2);  
        string temps;
        string strTemp;
        temps = s;                  //temporary val to store s
        cout << s;
        replace(s, s , newchamp);   //first parameter is where new string is stored, second param is             the old string and third param is what old string is being replaced by new string
        cout << s;
        while(yuumi >> strTemp)
        {
            if(strTemp == temps){
                cout << s;
                strTemp = s;
            }
            yuumi1 << strTemp;
        }
        yuumi.close();             //closes file for output
    
        yuumi1.close();              //closes file for input
        exit(0);        //just for testing purposes
```

I have tried changing many values by passing them by reference/not by reference, I have tried using fstream with ios::out and ios::in, I have tried using getline, I have tried moving the logic around; making sure all the variables are scoped correctly. At first glance I thought the issue was in the replace function since it returns a bool but after further inspection it also works as is. Originally, the FindFullLine function was made for fstream, but I changed it to ifstream in the parameters, I don't believe that would change much however. I also tried getting rid of the ifstream and ofstream.close(); functions. I have tried practically everything I can think of.Down below is a screenshot of the format I was attempting to copy.

[format of text in json file i was copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIsoY.png)

I believe I formatted everything correctly in my code in order to match exactly what is happening in the text file. But when I run the code, everything disappears and the text file is blank. Linked down below is the output that I get, there is a cout << statement after the replace function is ran to ensure that everything is working as intended, and from the output's point of view, everything is working correctly.
[output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYDgl.png)

Comment: Please don't attempt to do JSON parsing yourself, that is extremely complex and prone to failures. Please try to find a library which handles it all for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im confused as to exactly what JSON parsing is, I assumed I could do this the same way you can with text files, is that not possible? And if not, are there even any libraries built in out there for such a thing? Importing libraries is not really vscode's specialty, and I am too deep into this project being built in vscode that I cant transfer it to something like Visual Studio

Comment: FindFullLine seems to be wrong or I do not understand it. You are reading num lines, but only return the last, so one string.

Comment: If you *only* want to replace a specific text with another, then perhaps it's not needed to actually parse the JSON file, if you don't actually care about context, and to replace the text indiscriminately everywhere in the file. But if there's any kind of context needed, then you need to parse the input and then you really need a library to help you.

Comment: @AM The num line is telling the function what line of the file you want it to read.

Comment: As for plain text-file replacement it's not that trivial either, unless the string you want to insert is *exactly* the same length and format as the string you replace. If there's any differences in length or format or newlines you need to buffer the changes some way, and rewrite the whole file from start to end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This json file contains information for a python program to run, so you can change how it behaves by modifying just the text within the json file, so yes all I am attempting to do is change one word to another. It shouldn't be too complicated then right?

Comment: Actually, I would suggest you just make a simple Python script to read the JSON file, replace the data-element you need to replace, and save the JSON file again. Using the common Python [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Shouldn't take more than a few minutes if you're experienced with Python and the module.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you a lot, I know nothing about python but multiple times already have come across this crossroads, where doing it in python took me 5 minutes and was so simple while i spent hours trying to figure it out in c++. I'm sure I can figure out how to do it in python then, thank you.